# Find day of year with the lubridate package in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm looking to find the day of year for a POSIXct class object with lubridate. For example, [12-9-2015 is day 343](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/neubrew/Calendar.jsp).

It's easy to find the day of the week or month with lubridate:

```
> lubridate::wday("2015-12-09 04:27:56 EST", labels = T)
Wed
> lubridate::day("2015-12-09 04:27:56 EST")
9
```

Is there an easy way to do so for the day of the year? I've searched the documentation and other questions but have not (yet) found an answer.

Comment: No need for `lubridate`: `format(Sys.time(), "%j")`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The correct function is `yday`, as in

```
lubridate::yday(Sys.time())
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a more complicated way to do this before stumbling on this answer from u/blindjesse:

```
# compute the time interval from the first of the year until now
YTD = interval(floor_date(now(), unit='year'), now())
# compute the length of the interval in days, and discard the fractional part
as.integer(time_length(YTD, "day"))
```

By the way, an even more compact version of u/blindjesse's answer would be:

```
lubridate::yday(now())
```